# Should buttons' position/placement be standardised across the whole platform?

Tags: buttons, design-patterns, interface, web

I know that there have been threads about button placement, however what I'm asking is not a specific case. Rather, I would like to know regardless of contexts, should button placements be standardised across the whole platform?

For me, I think that it isn't as clear cut because both sides of the argument might have their valid points. For example, if the interaction was to open a new page/tab, the button (with a right-chevron signifier) be on the right. And when the context expands, the button (with a down-chevron signifier) will also still be on the right. This makes sense if we are trying to foster a sense of familiarity as we repeat our patterns. However, I also read this [article](https://uxdesign.cc/buttons-placement-and-order-bb1c4abadfcb) and his point is that it depends on the users' reading pattern (which is based on the design).

Let me know what you think! :)

Comment: Yes, consistency is helpful. But more important is whether the positioning is relevant given the content of the individual screen/page

Comment: Hi @Yogesch, thanks for your reply. So in the case where I put my buttons on the right, but in a particular instance, having it on the left makes more sense. Do you think I should break my pattern and put it on the left?

Comment: Yes. whatever requires the least amount of "effort" to understand. Do the most intuitive thing, from a user perspective. The rationale behind consistency is to not confuse the user from one screen to the next. So the design language should still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Consistency and design guidelines always are a good starting point. However, when "desire paths" emerge, do follow them with your users, even if this means breaking consistency. UX design always is in service of a user, with consistency being one of many tools to help you with that.